# CodeDom Nested Array

Tags: c#, arrays, codedom

As the title suggests, I am trying to "nest" - or create an array within an array in C# using CodeDom.

**Here is the line that I am trying to replicate:**

```
T.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] {} } );
```

**Where T.Invoke is a method.**

I am able to create the above line with *almost* no flaws. The only issue I have is creating the second set of "{}" brackets. Below is the code I used:

```
CodeMethodInvokeExpression invoke_expression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("T"),"Invoke",
new CodePrimitiveExpression(null),
new CodeArrayCreateExpression(typeof(object),
new CodeExpression[] {
new CodeArrayCreateExpression(typeof(string[]),
new CodeExpression[] {})} )));
```

Perhaps someone could make sense of my code, and maybe even find my error.

Thank you for any help,

Evan

Comment: What is the error? What is the output you receive?

Comment: I don't know C#, but would {} be a literal for the string? (a value?)

Comment: I wrote it in the question - The final set of "{}" brackets do not appear. So it looks like: T.Invoke(null, new object[] { new string[] } )

Comment: Would you have less problems with creating a `new string[0]`? (I haven't used CodeDom a lot, so that's just what comes to my ming).

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I had tried that as well though - thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an empty `CodeSnippetExpression` to coerce it into creating the brackets:

```
CodeMethodInvokeExpression invoke_expression = new CodeMethodInvokeExpression(
    new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("T"),
    "Invoke",
    new CodePrimitiveExpression(null),
    new CodeArrayCreateExpression(
        typeof(object),
        new CodeExpression[]
        {
            new CodeArrayCreateExpression(
                typeof(string[]),
                new CodeExpression[]
                {
                    new CodeSnippetExpression("")
                })/*CodeArrayCreateExpression */
        })/*CodeArrayCreateExpression */
    )/*CodeMethodInvokeExpression*/;
```

Comment: It works perfectly. How did you know that 'CodeSnippetExpression' Would create the brackets?

Comment: I've run into this problem before and learned that blank `CodeSnippetExpression`s are useful for getting CodeDom to output code it feels is "unnecessary".